# CRISPR screening and systems biology

Tags: genomics, gwas, crispr, systems-biology

I am not sure how to tackle this one, so I’ll explain the general idea I have in mind.

Given results of a CRISPR knockout screening experiment [(like in this paper)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06676-2) with two types of assays: control vs. treated with 5 time points per each of the assays.

Is there a way to use the screening data to perform systems biology [network analysis](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/training/online/course/network-analysis-protein-interaction-data-introduction/network-analysis-biology-0)? Something which is related to signal transduction, transcriptional regulatory, or metabolic networks?

Maybe something which uses Bayesian inference? Or something similar to [differentially expressed representation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ug/identifying-differentially-expressed-genes-from-rna-seq-data.html) of the CRISPR screening? Alternatively, a GWAS analysis similar to [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-13585-5)?

Comment: do you have a list of genes that you would like to investigate through network analysis?

Comment: @gabrielet, yes I do have such a list. Even a few related such lists. But I also want to incorporate the information from the up regulation and down regulation values I got in the analysis. Not just the list of genes

Answer (score 1):

What do you call screening results?
Do you have a kind of array with protein or RNA data?
If so, you can use several open-source tools available on the internet, like [Enrichr](https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Enrichr) or [network analyst](https://www.networkanalyst.ca) to better understand the pathways affected by your treatment.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06676-2

Comment: what's network analyst?

Comment: https://www.networkanalyst.ca

Answer (score 1):

To investigate genes through a network based approach you can use several tools. I don't know which level of programming you have or which tool you prefer but here is a brief overview of the possibilities you have.

You can look into established databases containing information about interactions like, for instance, [STRING](https://string-db.org). Or, you can build networks using the [wgcna](https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/) method with R.

Then, once you have your network you can analyse its properties and here you also have several tools available such as standalone, java-base software like [cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/), R libraries such as [igraph](https://igraph.org/r/), python libraries such as [networkX](https://networkx.github.io/) online tools like [centiserver](http://www.centiserver.org/)...

Also you can perform gene set enrichment analsysis, which means adding a further layer of biological information to you set of genes like metabolic pathways (from KEGG, for example) and molecular functions (from GeneOntology, for instance) (gsea) as [here](http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/doc/GSEAUserGuideFrame.html?_Interpreting_GSEA_Results), [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/fgsea/inst/doc/fgsea-tutorial.html), and [here](https://bioinformatics-core-shared-training.github.io/cruk-summer-school-2018/RNASeq2018/html/06_Gene_set_testing.nb.html#gsea-analysis).

Here there is also a nice [tutorial](http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph) about network analysis with R.

---